# Apache 2.2.14 + php_apc.dll crash

Tags: php, windows, apache, apc

I can't get APC to work on Windows because Apache keeps crashing as soon as I run a php file. Is this issue know and is there a workaround?

Versions:
Apache 2.2.14 
PHP 3.1
APC 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best route to solve this type of problem is to check your Apache log files and see what issues were raised. An example of these logs follows:

```
[Wed Jun 03 06:07:47 2009] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/WebsiteA/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed Jun 03 06:08:16 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/kohana, referer: http://localhost/WebsiteB/website/
```

Comment: Oh yes, silly me. I just checked out the system log and forgot to look into the Apache error log...

It seems like the error is related to Zend Framework